# Return variable from within array.find()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a function which, when called with two arguments, checks the arguments against some supplementary data and if the return is `false`, returns the field.

I wish to return one of the elements if `false` and ignore/ return undefined if `true`.

```
  getFirstInvalidField() {
    const allFields = this.getPassengerDetailsFieldsRefs();
    allFields[0].find(function (field){
      if (!this.isValidField(field, 0)) {
        return field;
      }
    }, this);
  }
```

So when `isValidField` returns `false`, it should return `field` to the place where `getFirstInvalidField()` was called. This does not seem to be happening.

```
const firstInvalidField = this.getFirstInvalidField();
```

This should return `field` but instead returns `undefined` always. It seems the `return field` statement is not getting passed back and assigned to `firstInvalidField`

Comment: [The docs says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) "_The find() method returns a value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned._"

Comment: @Teemu yes, and it should have been satisfied and returned?

Comment: Put a `return` before `allFields[0].find()`.  You're returning the result into the function, but not then returning the result *from* the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return in function `getFirstInvalidField()` the value returned by `allFields[0].find()` as such:

```
getFirstInvalidField() {
  const allFields = this.getPassengerDetailsFieldsRefs();
  return allFields[0].find(function (field){
    if (!this.isValidField(field, 0)) {
      return field;
    }
  }, this);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return a `true` or `false` response from `find()` callback. Also return the result to function caller.

```
getFirstInvalidField() {
  const allFields = this.getPassengerDetailsFieldsRefs();
  return allFields[0].find(function (field){
    return !this.isValidField(field, 0);
  }, this);
}
```